# export module from a asynchronous functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have function which is basically being used for scraper and has recursion value but now I want to export it as module so I can call it in a router, but i am not sure how do i export this function in `module.exports`

```
(async () => {
    const pages = async url => {
})();
```

Comment: Note that your code is nothing, right now. It's invalid JS (please fix that), but even with the correct number of matched parentheses and brackets, this won't return anything because of how arrow functions work. (any explicit scope means you need an explicit `return`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

export it *instead* of calling it: remove those final `()`:

```
module.exports = async () => {
  ...
};
```

However, since you're not preserving any declaration context (and why would you?) there is no reason to use arrow notation.

```
module.exports = async function() {
  ...
};
```